# iPhone 4s leaking weird substance, has 2 small shadow bumps on the side of screen, and is getting hot very quickly

Tags: iphone, hardware

It is only a little more than a year old! On the bottom right of the screen, there are 2 small bumps of shadows, it has been heating up VERY quickly, and is leaking a very weird, clear, oil-like substance. I have shutting it off but it didn't work! Also in the middle right of the screen there is a patch of very white splotches!

Comment: Get it away from anything it could harm, especially yourself!

Comment: Do not leave it anywhere where if it catches fire the fire will spread.

Comment: As a little more that a year old it could be still under warranty - so take it back to the shop you bought it from (I am in the EU and would hope other countries have similar consumer protection)

Comment: Turn it off and put it in a plastic box to contain the leaking fluid (keep an eye on it in any case).  Take it to an Apple Store and ask them what to do.

Answer (score 8):

Internal pressure is almost certainly a safety issue and battery failure mode. Same for anything leaking out. Even if the substance entered the phone and not something decomposing from the materials made into the phone, you don't want electrical shorts or anything leaving the case of an iPhone.

Think **potential fire hazard** if the battery is swelling or leaking and get the hardware to someone that is qualified to diagnose a failing battery and physical damage. Call Apple if you can't take it to someone for service. 1-800-APL-CARE

Do not charge it or connect to any USB - I would power it off immediately from the description you have listed.

You can also get safety information from: http://www.apple.com/us/search/iphone-safety?find=iphone+safety and select Support to narrow the results to specific hardware safety and manual download instructions.

Once you have some guidance, you might power it on one more time to perform a backup if you don't have a recent one. Again, don't leave it unattended until you're sure it's stable and working correctly. If you can't get it cooled, consider calling for help - local fire department if needed.

Comment: Also consider that it's likely to explode, so wear glasses, gloves, etc. if you need to handle it and try and put some mass between it and anything sensitive (yourself included) - i. e. heavy books/etc. that can absorb an explosion - there are plenty of videos on youtube about li batteries exploding if you are still skeptical about it